# Id Value is not valid for standard controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, pagemessages

I am getting the error mentioned in subject with below code when execution runs through **Else** condition without DML statement. I am not getting how to change Pagereference?

**Apex Code**

```
 AllocQ= useravailbleQty ;

      system.debug('AllocQ@@'+AllocQ);
      AllocatedQuantity=String.valueOf(AllocQ);
      Qty=Test.Requested_Quantity_abv__c;
     If(AllocatedQuantity>=Qty || AllocatedQuantity==null )
     {try {
            upsert (this.Test); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
          system.debug('Failed@@');
           // return null;
        }

     }
     else {
         ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: a.    You do not have sufficient allocations to complete this request.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);

          }
       // }

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/FormRequestPage?id='+this.test.id);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
```

Comment: Not clear where you are getting error. Which part of your code?

Comment: This line is the root cause. PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/FormRequestPage?id='+this.test.id);  id=null coming in URL

Comment: So what is the `this.test` is it a record?

Comment: Check if the `Id` field is get populated correctly. Also it's not a good idea to use system key words like `test` for custom implementations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Id is null in your **else** case, so this.test record was not inserted. Record does not have an Id until it is inserted in the database. Make sure you insert your record before that **else** otherwise your logic won`t work.

Comment: Yes it is null , I need pagereference only if DML is successful

Comment: But then you might want to add an if statement before your pageRef to check if that id is not null. Or move pageref just after the upsert, so if it will fail you won`t get there.

Answer (score 0):

Please go on apex page "FormRequestPage" and check the name of standard controller.

Like in your case Suppose your standard controller is Account object then "this.test.id" should be Account rcord Id.

You are passing wrong id here means another object's record id.