# VF page doesn't show the fields

Tags: visualforce, tasks, standardcontroller, console, custom-console-components

I've the following code for a task object which redirects after clicking one of the record types which I am trying to add onto my custom console components

```
<apex:page standardController="task">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Task Edit" subtitle="{!task.Subject}"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Task Edit" mode="edit">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save & New" action="{!save}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>


            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Fields" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.eSVS_no__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Class_subclass_mix_list__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.QC_no__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Vendor__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Instock_S_o__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.What_Vendor_Won__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Department_Categories__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Disposition__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Description__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Subject}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Summary__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.ActivityDate}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Priority}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Status}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.OwnerId}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.WhatId}" required="false"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!task.Name__c}" required="false"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If I click the preview button, it takes me to the edit page.
But when i Add this to my custom console component it says :"Id value a02g000000E64Dg is not valid for the Task standard controller "

I am attaching the screenshot here.

What could possibly go wrong here?

Thank you 
Venkat[image]

Comment: Can you check you have correct permissions for Object and fields.

Comment: Refer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110772/id-value-is-not-valid-for-standard-controller

Comment: @Ashwani, I do have the system administrator profile and yes i do have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're passing the record ID of some other object to the page, not a task. The prefix for a task ID is `00T`, you have `a02` which leads me to believe you're passing the ID of a custom object since that prefix isn't in [Daniel's comprehensive list](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html).

Check the code for where you're including this component and double check what record ID you're passing to it.

Comment: as right mentioned by @Matt, you need to verify the ID you are passing to custom console component. The page's standardcontroller is receiving an ID of record which is not a TASK, hence it's throwing error

Comment: Its related to the store object. Its picking up the data from the lookup field which is automatically filled when you click the "new task" button. I am new to this visualforce. what am i supposed to change it here?